# Package R does not exist Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, r.java-file

I am trying to set up Action Bar Sherlock using IntelliJ. I created the android module as a library and then I attached it as a module dependency in my target project. When I build I get the error

> java: package R does not exist

I get 100 of these errors.

When I looked at some other posts, it seemed that people who were using Eclipse just cleaned the project. However, I dont see any option to clean a project in IntelliJ. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some error on your xml files, double check them, rebuild your project and try again.

After that you may want to check if you are including the right `R` in your imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code there below problems:

1. Package which is not related to `com.actionbarsherlock` check mannually and delete that package.
2. in your layout files(XML) resource are not available like String,Images.... etc.
3. You have't add Jar Files in `Java Build Path` & you must have to select all in `Java Build Path --> Order & export ---> Select all`.

   After doing all above clean your code..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try File > Invalidate Caches and then restart your IDE.

As suggested here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html